# Ретинизация на адаптиве

Tags: css, scss, retina

Всем привет! 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема.
Делаю mobile first. Для фона картинка bg-students, для ретины bg-studens@2x. Все работает. 
Создал медиазапрос для планшетной версии. 
Все тоже самое, но фоновая картинка bg-students-tab@2x на ретине не отображается, т.к она переопределена как раз таки фоном bg-students@2x.png еще с мобильной версии. 
Как можно исправить?  Заранее спасибо

```
    $width-tablet: "(min-width: 768px)";
    $retina-dpi: 144dpi;
    $retina-dppx: 1.5dppx;
.header {    

    &--students {
            background-image: url("/img/1/2/bg-students.png");
            @media (min-resolution: $retina-dpi), (min-resolution: $retina-dppx) {
                background-image: url("/img/1/2/bg-students@2x.png");
            }
            @media #{$width-tablet} {
                background-image: url("/img/1/2/bg-students-tab.png");
                @media (min-resolution: $retina-dpi), (min-resolution: $retina-dppx) {
                    background-image: url("/img/1/2/bg-students-tab@2x.png");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Решено:
Добавил медиазапрос для мобильных версий

```
&--workers {
        @media #{$width-mobile} {
            background-image: url("/img/1/2/bg-workers.png");
            @media (min-resolution: $retina-dpi), (min-resolution: $retina-dppx) {
                background-image: url("/img/1/2/bg-workers@2x.png");
            }
        }
        @media #{$width-tablet} {
            background-image: url("/img/1/2/bg-workers-tab.png");
            @media (min-resolution: $retina-dpi), (min-resolution: $retina-dppx) {
                background-image: url("/img/1/2/bg-workers-tab@2x.png");
            }
        }
        @media #{$width-desktop} {
            background-image: url("/img/1/2/bg-workers-desk.png");
            background-position: center;
            @media (min-resolution: $retina-dpi), (min-resolution: $retina-dppx) {
                background-image: url("/img/1/2/bg-workers-desk@2x.png");
            }
        }
    }
```